# How can I achieve the following using PHP? <img src="Value from DB">

Tags: php, html

How can I prefix the img src with a value from my db.

Example
From my DB table `"tbl1"`, for each row how can I prefix img src with value of `$row['image']`

If `$row['image']` = `sunshine`

then the output of

```
echo 
"<div class='image'>
<img src=" . $row['image'] . ".png">
</div>"
```

should be `sunshine.png` thus loading my image where and when I need it.

Here is what I have so far but I can't get it to work. The image does not display, I don't see any errors

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo 
                                "<div class='image'>
                                <img src=" . $row['image'] . "".png">
                                </div>";
                                       }
                                    
        
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else{
                echo "<p class='lead'>
                                <em>Error</em></p>";
             }
        } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }

    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: you're probably breaking those quotations that's why it's malformed when rendered in html. escape those double quotes if you want them inside the double quoted string in PHP. an alternative way to check is to view it in inspect element of the browser. you'll see that malformed source attribute, that's why the image tag doesn't show up properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$img = $row['image'].".png";                
echo "<div class='image'>
          <img src=" . $img . ">
       </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jumbling of double quotes.

Please use single quotes and double quotes interchangeably.

```
echo 
                                    '<div class="image">
                                    <img src="' . $row['image'] . '.png"'>
                                    </div>';
```